# Best way to upload several thousand files?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

So I need to be able to consistently have users uploading 3,000 to 4,000 images at a time. Currently using dropzonejs, which works fine for around 1,000-2,000 images, but higher than that and I start to have issues. The images are ~2MB in size, get resized client side to ~300KB, then sent to the server. Resizing server side is not currently an option, so I'm not sure what else I can do. Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay so we seem to have found what may be factoring in to the issue with such high memory usage when adding a large amount of files. The issue seems to be caused by a few simple div statements using some bootstrap classes.

Every 1000 photos added (before even starting the upload), is causing an increase of about ~400MB in memory. Here is what seems to be causing huge increases in memory usage:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span class="name" data-dz-name></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span class="size" data-dz-size></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove bootstrap column classes from the divs, I only get an increase of about ~3mb per 1000 photos added. What could be going wrong with the bootstrap classes that would cause 400MB increases in memory usage...

Comment: are you having issues server-side in handling the load? in either case, what exactly are these issues you're having

Comment: Resizing server-side wouldn't seem to be an option anyways. I'm sure sending 8 *gigs* (4000 images at 2mb) of images across the network isn't going to be any better. I have to imagine you're going to wind up hitting hard limits in on memory consumption in the browser at some point, unless you're carefully making sure everything can be garbage collected.

Comment: I have two issues really. 1) When it gets to around to 2000th photo, it starts sending requests with no data. I assume that client side I am running out of memory due to some sort of garbage collection issue. 2) If I try to add ~4000 photos at once, chrome will crash. I assume this has to do with the way html file upload works, and everything is first loaded in to memory?

Comment: As this is a likely to be a memory management issue, can you post code of how you're resizing images and submitting to server?

Comment: @jasonscript added some more information. any ideas?